# KafkaTemplate send method safe to use without manual (blocking) check of returned future

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I use the KafkaTemplate of `spring-kafka` for producing some messages to kafka.

I have a simple rest API which could be used for creating messages.
Inside my code i use the KafkaTemplate like this for producing my message to kafka.

```
kafkaTemplate.send("topic", "key", "data")
```

It's important for me that I only give back a success to the client when the message was really send.

But now i realised that the method is at least partially asynchron.
The signature of the method is:

```
    public ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> send(String topic, K key, @Nullable V data) {
```

So it returns a future and the future could eventually call the failure callback when it will be resolved.

I have looked a little bit under the hood in the java code of spring-kafka (version 2.2.6) and it seems like there are some error which will be thrown directly and some which will be only available by resolving the future, there is also a javadoc for it which looks like:

```
            // handling exceptions and record the errors;
            // for API exceptions return them in the future,
            // for other exceptions throw directly
```

My main question is: Do I have to resolve the future (which includes API exception) in a blocking way for finding out if something goes wrong on send; so that I can be 100% sure that my message was send correctly?

Or is the sending itself already guaranteed when the `send` method don't throw any exception and the error inside the future are only about issues on receiving back some meta information? (or something similar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to block on the get to detect a failure, the other option is to add a callback to the future to get the result asynchronously. (It is a `ListenableFuture`).

```java
public interface ListenableFutureCallback<T> extends SuccessCallback<T>, FailureCallback {

}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface SuccessCallback<T> {

    /**
     * Called when the {@link ListenableFuture} completes with success.
     * <p>Note that Exceptions raised by this method are ignored.
     * @param result the result
     */
    void onSuccess(@Nullable T result);

}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface FailureCallback {

    /**
     * Called when the {@link ListenableFuture} completes with failure.
     * <p>Note that Exceptions raised by this method are ignored.
     * @param ex the failure
     */
    void onFailure(Throwable ex);

}
```

There are no guarantees of success if you just send (and pray).

**EDIT**

Client side exceptions (e.g. serialization) are thrown on the calling thread, but server side will be completed on the future asynchronously.

There are a number of server-side errors that might result in an async failure; see the `Errors` class...

```java
/**
 * This class contains all the client-server errors--those errors that must be sent from the server to the client. These
 * are thus part of the protocol. The names can be changed but the error code cannot.
 *
 * Note that client library will convert an unknown error code to the non-retriable UnknownServerException if the client library
 * version is old and does not recognize the newly-added error code. Therefore when a new server-side error is added,
 * we may need extra logic to convert the new error code to another existing error code before sending the response back to
 * the client if the request version suggests that the client may not recognize the new error code.
 *
 * Do not add exceptions that occur only on the client or only on the server here.
 */
public enum Errors {
    UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR(-1, "The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request.",
            UnknownServerException::new),
    NONE(0, null, message -> null),
    OFFSET_OUT_OF_RANGE(1, "The requested offset is not within the range of offsets maintained by the server.",
            OffsetOutOfRangeException::new),
    CORRUPT_MESSAGE(2, "This message has failed its CRC checksum, exceeds the valid size, has a null key for a compacted topic, or is otherwise corrupt.",
            CorruptRecordException::new),
    UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION(3, "This server does not host this topic-partition.",
            UnknownTopicOrPartitionException::new),
    INVALID_FETCH_SIZE(4, "The requested fetch size is invalid.",
            InvalidFetchSizeException::new),
    LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE(5, "There is no leader for this topic-partition as we are in the middle of a leadership election.",
            LeaderNotAvailableException::new),
...
```

Comment: Some exceptions will be thrown in a synchron way so maybe the successful sending is already guranteed when this synchron exceptions aren't thrown. But I don't know it...

Comment: No; any server-side exceptions will be returned asynchronously. Only client side errors (e.g. serialization) will be thrown on the calling thread.

Comment: Great that what I need to know. Could you explain it a little bit further (why you are sure about it) in a new answer. Then I would like to accept this answer.

Comment: They don't like multiple answers from the same person here. See the edit.